# R - fit histogram: peaked signal plus background

Tags: r, histogram, curve-fitting

I need to fit with R an histogram containing a peaked signal plus a flat background. Like these:

[Google Images Link](https://www.google.it/search?q=signal+plus+background&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=Tz6xU8zTJ_Pb7Ab74YCwCA&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=920#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=uEPi2KWaZEaaRM%253A%3B9wYKcWTJ0ARIuM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwwwasd.web.cern.ch%252Fwwwasd%252Fpaw%252Fcontributions%252Fbwp4_fit.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwwwasd.web.cern.ch%252Fwwwasd%252Fpaw%252Fcontributions%252Ffit_kumac_examples.html%3B529%3B483) to:

[pic http://wwwasd.web.cern.ch/wwwasd/paw/contributions/bwp4_fit.gif](http://wwwasd.web.cern.ch/wwwasd/paw/contributions/bwp4_fit.gif)

How can I do efficiently in R? I haven't found any good reference on the web.
I was used to do this in ROOT: http://root.cern.ch/root/html/tutorials/fit/FittingDemo.C.html
but in R it's not so easy...

I did something using fitdistr (MASS package), but it woks well only if I use a single given distribution (e.g. a gaussian).
If I try to add to the gaussian a flat (uniform) background, adding a parameter for the relative presence of the two distributions:

```
f = gaus(mean, sigma) + r * uniform
```

with mean, sigma and r free parameters, the fit doesn't work anymore.

Typical errors are:

```
Error in solve.default(res$hessian) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0
In addition: There were 28 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

or simply there's no convergence.

Finally, I don't understand how R deals with normalization constants (multiplicative parameters in front of each added distribution). I guess that if we fit the frequencies everything (histogram and fit curve) should be already normalized to unity.. By consequence the only new parameter when adding a flat background to the peaked signal should be the relative weight (r in the above example). Is this the case?

Thanks
Marco

Comment: There's no histogram there. Your pasted image has no background offset.  If you want substantive help, you'll need to post your exact code and a reproducible data sample.  In the meantime, a guess: several fitting routines will fail in the absense of noise. It's possible that by feeding `solve.default` a 'perfect' dataset, you get a singular matrix somewhere.

Comment: The image was just an example taken from google, to describe the concept. Anyway the code with precise dataset can be something like this:

b <- runif(1000, 0, 10)
s <- rnorm(n=500, 4, 0.3)
sb <- c(b,s)

hist(sb,breaks = 100)